# Undefined property: stdClass::$labels in general-template.php post_type_archive_title()

Tags: custom-post-types, tags, errors, notices

I've got a custom post type with a standard tag taxonomy added to it like so: `'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')`. I've added some tags to some posts of this CPT which are display on the front-end with the template tag `the_tags()` and the links it generates have this format `http://local.mysite.dev/tag/tag1/`. When I click such a link a page without any posts is generated using the `tag.php` template, but if I add `?post_type=seron_mycpt` to the end of the URL like so `http://local.mysite.dev/tag/tag1/?post_type=seron_mycpt` a page with the relevant posts is generated using the same template but this time I also get these lines added to `debug.log`:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$labels in /...sitepath.../wp-includes/general-template.php on line 665
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /...sitepath.../wp-includes/general-template.php on line 665
```

These notices are produced when `wp_title()` is called in the `header.php` template. According to the rewrite rules the request is transformed into the query `tag=tag1&post_type=seron_mycpt`.

For debugging I put `print_r(get_queried_object());` in `header.php` and got this:

```
MYSITEstdClass Object
(
 [term_id] => 27
 [name] => tag1
 [slug] => tag1
 [term_group] => 0
 [term_taxonomy_id] => 27
 [taxonomy] => post_tag
 [description] =>
 [parent] => 0
 [count] => 2
)
```

I think WP expects a CPT object with a `labels` property but gets this object instead which doesn't have that property.

If I tag an ordinary `post` with the same tag, the same `header.php` and `tag.php` templates are used and that post is displayed when using the `http://local.mysite.dev/tag/tag1/` URL, and in that case no PHP notices are produced in `debug.log`, although `print_r(get_queried_object())` shows a very similar object. Maybe WP never reaches the notice-producing line in `general-template.php`.

I don't understand what this object is and why it is passed instead of a CPT object. Could someone explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug (one that I've encountered before) and could do with a ticket in [trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/) (since I never took the time to submit one!)

The trouble starts with requests that set multiple `is_*` query flags as true (specifically flags that represent objects, such as single posts, pages, and post type & term archives).

This is because there can only ever be one "queried object" (in your case it's the term).

Now the reason `wp_title()` seems to throw a wobbly is down to another function it calls:

```
function post_type_archive_title( $prefix = '', $display = true ) {
    if ( ! is_post_type_archive() )
        return;

    $post_type_obj = get_queried_object();
    $title = apply_filters('post_type_archive_title', $post_type_obj->labels->name );

    if ( $display )
        echo $prefix . $title;
    else
        return $title;
}
```

Since the `is_post_type_archive` flag is true, it assumes the queried object is a post type, and tries to access an undefined property of what is actually a term object.

Whether the fix is to open up the possibility of multiple queried objects, or to implement more rigourous checking of them, I'm not sure, but I'll get it on trac & we'll see what follows.

**Update:** To suppress the error (& possible others), "switch off" one of the flags:

```
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpse_71157_parse_query' );
function wpse_71157_parse_query( $wp_query )
{
    if ( $wp_query->is_post_type_archive && $wp_query->is_tax )
        $wp_query->is_post_type_archive = false;
}
```

Comment: Found an [existing ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21821) - use this to submit any comments/patches.

Comment: I read in this [comment in a related ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18614#comment:14) that a filter can be used to rebuild the title but the commenter doesn't elaborate. I've never created a filter myself. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I assume they're referring to the `wp_title` filter that the function `wp_title()` applies before output - but that still wouldn't suppress the notice (see update for how to do just that).

Comment: Thank you. That fixed both the title and suppressed the notices, like you said. I modified it slightly to check is_tag instead of is_tax, and learned a lot in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did. In my taxonomy archive template I was relying on is_post_type_archive() to output additional div tags.

```
add_action( 'parse_query', 'orb_parse_query' );

function orb_parse_query( $wp_query ) {  
    global $post_type_obj;

    if ( $wp_query->is_post_type_archive && $wp_query->is_tax ) {
        $post_type_obj = get_queried_object();

        if (empty($post_type_obj->labels)) {
            $post_type_obj->labels = new stdClass();
            $post_type_obj->labels->name = 'dev/hack to fix WordPress Bug';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for help. I used solution from lordspace and little modified it, to show the name of the current custom post type.

```
add_action( 'parse_query', 'orb_parse_query' );

function orb_parse_query( $wp_query ) {  
    global $post_type_obj;

    if ( $wp_query->is_post_type_archive && $wp_query->is_tax ) {
        $post_type_obj = get_queried_object();

        if (empty($post_type_obj->labels)) {
            $currentPostType = $wp_query->query['post_type'];
            $currentPostTypeName = get_post_type_object($currentPostType)->labels->name;
            $post_type_obj->labels = new stdClass();
            $post_type_obj->labels->name = $currentPostTypeName;
        }
    }
}
```