# rewriting for custom taxonomy rewrite

Tags: custom-taxonomy, rewrite-rules

I want to rewrite my custom taxonomy in form of

http://mywebsite.com/cars/my-tax

All examples i found makes use rewrites and use a new function to get the new permalink... problem is normally to get a term url, get_term_link is used but I cannot use this as I have rewritten the permalink.. so i need to replace this function everywhere it is called? does not seem to be a good solution for me.

Comment: it's not clear what your issue is. please add the code you are using to your question.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is pass the URL structure in the arguments when registering your custom taxonomy. For example:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_taxonomy' );
function register_my_taxonomy() {
    $args = array(
          //Complete the arguments for your taxonomy
          // The rewrite argument should looks like this
          'rewrite' = array( "slug" => "cars/my-tax" )
     );
    register_taxonomy( 'my-tax', 'my-post-type', $args );
}
```

You may need to flush the rewrite rules; you can do it just visiting the permlink settings page in you wordpress admin area.

Also, if you have a custom post-type called 'cars', it is possible that you get a PHP error when viewing the tax archive pages in the front end using the URL 'cars/my-tax'. You can suppress this error with this:

```
/*
This supress an error with Undefined property: stdClass::$labels in general_template.php
See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71157/undefined-property-stdclasslabels-in-general-template-php-post-type-archive
*/
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpse_71157_parse_query' );
function wpse_71157_parse_query( $wp_query ) {
    if ( $wp_query->is_post_type_archive && $wp_query->is_tax ) {
         $wp_query->is_post_type_archive = false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: setting the rewrite slug already generates the rewrite rules, why do you also add redundant rewrite rules?

Comment: I thought they are needed, are not they? Great to know.